# Getting status of XMLHttpRequest variable from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have the problem that the var from PHP is 1 but JavaScript doesn't want me to give me the corresponding status for var 1. I have little experience with JavaScript, so sorry about the shitty code.

```
function plzcheck(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "Login/plzcheck.php";
    var plz = document.getElementById("Postleitzahl").value;
    var vars = "plz="+plz;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'progressing...'
}  
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(return_data == 1){
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {                
            $('.containerlogin').stop().addClass('active');
            document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "Deine PLZ ist Verfügbar!";
        }
    } else {                    
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {        
            $('.containerlogin').stop().addClass('active');
            document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "Leider ist deine PLZ noch nicht Verfügbar. Registriere dich und wir geben dir bescheid, wenn es losgeht!";
        }
    }
}
```

What went wrong here? I expect to get the first message, but I always get the last one: "Leider ist deine..."

Comment: At least properly indent your code.

Comment: Why are you continually overwriting onreadystatechange? `hr.onreadystatechange = function() {`. Also since you appear to be using jQuery why not use the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) method

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will use jquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
$('.containerlogin').stop().addClass('active');


if(hr.responseText == "plzda"){



      document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "Deine PLZ ist Verfügbar!";

                 } else {   


        document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "Leider ist deine PLZ noch nicht Verfügbar. Registriere dich und wir geben dir bescheid, wenn es losgeht!";
     }
 }

     }
```

> Solved!